# When making foreach with DirectoryInfo what should be the in?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void CountFiles(DirectoryInfo di, List<FileInfo> l, Action<int> CurrentCount) {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subDirs)
                CountFiles(dir, l, currentCount=> {
                    CurrentCount(l.Count);

                });
        }
```

The variable subDirs is not exist but if it was exist what it should be ? What type ?

Comment: This is really unclear what you're asking. Please be more specific what are you trying to do, what's the problem, and what have you tried so far

Comment: It is very clear what OP is asking, if you have any confusion atleast comment and ask OP to more explain before casting a **Close Vote**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`GetDirectories()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=vs.110).aspx) method of [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
private void CountFiles(DirectoryInfo di, List<FileInfo> l, Action<int> CurrentCount) {
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
        CountFiles(dir, l, currentCount=> {
            CurrentCount(l.Count);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As name of varabiales says, it should hold subdirectories of current directory.
So

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{ 
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll find the method you're looking for. The value of subDirs would be an array of DirectoryInfo.

So:

```
DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = di.GetDirectories();
```